# How to make an application client jar file for IBM's launchclient

Tags: jar, client, websphere

Hi I'm facing with a bug in old ejb application which is deployed on IBM Websphere 6.1. Previously it ran but now it stopped for some reason which I have to investigate.
I'm trying to get it to run locally on my desktop, and I'm trying to access the session bean with  IBM's launchclient application. I pass in the ear as the argument (yes that's IBM specific) and the ears contains both the ejb-jar and the ejb-client.jar (also IBM specific).

Launchclient fails with the message:  *myear* does not contain an Application Client jar file. Which may be true, but it does contain the client-ejb jar file, which I even bothered to address with -CCjar=MyEjbClient.jar. 
My question is how can I make an application client jar file?

I cant find much information on the launchclient thing, I do have RAD 7.x or something, but to be honest I want to stay away from it as much as possible and it's getting really frustrating.

regards,

PS someone knows a nice NO IBM job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not sufficient to have an ejb-client-jar, you need an application client JAR.  Also, -CCjar can only be specified for an application jar (and it's not necessary if you only have one).

To add an application client JAR to an EAR, you need to:

1. Create a Java class with a traditional main method.
2. Package the class in a JAR in the EAR.
3. Add a Main-Class to the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in the JAR.
4. Add a META-INF/application-client.xml file to the JAR.
5. Add the module to application.xml in the EAR:

   ```
   <module>
     <java>MyClient.jar</java>
   </module>
   ```